# Calculate moving in cost with multiple criterias

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

I need to calculate the moving cost for every store by product, so here's my dataset below:

If Moving Units is Negative, that means it's moving from that store.
If Moving units is positive, means  units moving in from other store.

```
  Product Code  Store code   Original Price     Moving Units    Moving  Cost
       Shoe 1   LA1            $50.00           (700)            $(35,000.00)
       Shoe 1   LA2            $56.00            300             $15,000.00 
       Shoe 1   LA3            $54.00            400             $20,000.00 
       Shoe 2   LA1            $57.33           (200)            $(11,466.67)
       Shoe 2   LA2            $59.33            500             $29,866.67 
       Shoe 2   SA1            $61.33           (900)            $(55,200.00)
       Shoe 2   SA2            $63.33            600             $36,800.00
```

So scenario 1 would be:
Both Store LA2 and LA3 Moving units comes from Store LA1,
so the moving cost will be just Moving units * LA1 Original Price:

```
     Product Code   Store code   Original Price     Moving Units    Moving  Cost
           Shoe 1   LA1            $50.00           (700)            $(35,000.00)
           Shoe 1   LA2            $56.00            300             $15,000.00 
           Shoe 1   LA3            $54.00            400             $20,000.00
```

And Scenario 2

Store LA2 moving in units comes from two different store and Store SA1 Moving units moves to two different store as well.

So Moving cost for LA2 = 200 Moving Units* LA1 original price + 300 moving units *SA1 original price

```
Product Code  Store code   Original Price     Moving Units    Moving  Cost
       Shoe 2   LA1            $57.33           (200)            $(11,466.67)
       Shoe 2   LA2            $59.33            500             $29,866.67 
       Shoe 2   SA1            $61.33           (900)            $(55,200.00)
       Shoe 2   SA2            $63.33            600             $36,800.00
```

To calculate the moving cost is very manual at this moment. I basically type the formula row by row.
Is there anyway I can make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can see would be to insert a helper column to find the store's original price for use in the calculation. **If the negative always comes first**, then you could add a formula such as:

```
=If([Moving Units]>0,value of cell above,[Original Price])
```

Then multiply that value by [Moving Units] to get Moving Cost..

[image]

Apologies, the formatting changed when recreating this but the values are what's important.

Comment: This works!! Though in my dataset is not always negative comes first. Would you suggest I add more criteria in the IF function or there's other way to do it?

Comment: You need to define a way to identify the original price. If not the first instance of a negative Moving Units, then what could you use? In your example, I did notice that a combination of Product Code and first two characters of Store Code could also be used - but that might be just because of your sample data and not usable in real life. Ask yourself - how do ***I*** identify the actual original price and turn that into logic/prodcedure.